# Open Windows Firewall to all connections from specific IP Address

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, ipv4, whitelist, rules

Is it possible to "whitelist" an IP Address in the Windows Firewall and allow all connections from that specific address?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming the IP address you want to whitelist is `192.0.2.55`:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow from 192.0.2.55" dir=in action=allow protocol=ANY remoteip=192.0.2.55
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to disable all of the other allow rules or connections will still make it through from them.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to do it from Powershell

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name Allow192.0.2.55 -DisplayName 'Allow from 192.0.2.55' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol ANY -Action Allow -Profile ANY -RemoteAddress 192.0.2.55
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work like charm

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="my rule" new remoteip=157.60.0.67
```